# Image in rails asset pipeline loading indefinitely, but still appearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Okay so basically, I have a file in my asset pipeline (http://myapp.dev/assets/avatars/default-avatar.jpg). When I visit the URL, the image loads, but continues to act as though it's transferring data (the chrome spinner is spinning). If I access the same file in production instead of development, it works just fine. In addition, no other files have this issue, it's only that ONE jpeg in that ONE folder.

I have no clue what this could be. Can anyone help?

EDIT: This is what the network activity looks like [image: network activity]

Comment: Does this happen when you launch the site via webrick or thin locally, or just when you use pow? What about if you browse the image directly? How about other browsers (I see the chrome extension in your screenshot causing some activity)?

Comment: It might also be worth trying this with both Webrick and Thin to see if there is a difference.

Comment: It seems the behavior was the same with Thin and Webrick. I got a fix for it though -- I just resaved the image from Photoshop and for some reason now it works... Weird. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (the image would show up but continue to load for a long period of time, then the transfer would ultimately fail and the image would appear broken).

Saving the image again in Photoshop resolved it for me, as you mentioned in your comment above. Must have been something wrong with the image encoding.